# Grouping in SSRS 2008 - Filtering

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm new to SSRS. I want to group a transactions table by customerid and count how many transactions per customerid. I was able to do that.

But then I want to sort by that count, and/or filter by that count. How do you that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To set up sorting and filtering on row groups, right click on the row group.

You can access the Group Sorting and Filtering properties here. They should both allow you to set up rules based on the name of your count column.

Comment: It doesn't let me sort by an aggregate.

Comment: you can sort by an aggregate. i do it all the time.

Comment: If you do it all the time, maybe you could provide a sample with function for the newbies..

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

If you have no need to show the transactions in the report then the aggregation should be performed at the database level in the query, not by SSRS. You'll get the benefits of:

1. Faster rendering.

   - You'll be sending less data over the network.
   - There'll be less data for the SSRS engine to process, therefore any ordering can be performed quicker.
2. Your data set can be 'pre-ordered' by putting the most common/expected values in the `ORDER BY` clause of the underlying query.

   - Thereby giving any rendering a speed boost, also.
3. Any filters can be applied directly against the aggregated data returned by the query without having to try and do complex expressions in SSRS.

   - This will also give a performance boost when rendering.
4. You could have a "filter" parameter that could be used in the `HAVING` clause of an aggregate query

   - Again, a performance boost due to less data across the network, and to be processed.
   - Gives a level of interactivity to your reports as opposed to trying to pre-define user tastes and having filter conditions set on expressions or a 'best-guess'.

### Example

```sql
-- Will filter out any customers who have 2 or fewer transactions
DECLARE @Filter AS int = 2
;

SELECT 
    CustomerId
    ,COUNT(TransactionId)

FROM
    Transactions

GROUP BY
    CustomerId

HAVING
     COUNT(TransactionId) > @Filter
```

---

## Option 2

If you still need to show the transactions, then add an additional column to your query that performs the `Count()` using the `OVER` clause and `PARTITION BY customerid`, like so:

```
COUNT(transactions) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid) AS CustomerTransactionCount
```

Assuming a very simple table structure you'll end up with a query structure like so:

```sql
SELECT
    CustomerId
    ,TransactionId
    ,TransactionAttribute_1
    ,TransactionAttribute_2
    ,TransactionAttribute_3
    .
    .
    .
    ,TransactionAttribute_n
    ,COUNT(TransactionId) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId) AS CustomerTransactionCount

FROM
    Transactions
```

You'll be able to use `CustomerTransactionCount` as a filter and sorting column in any row/column groups within SSRS.

#### Drawback of this approach

- Window functions, i.e. using the `OVER (PARTITION BY...)` cannot be used in `HAVING` clauses as no `GROUP BY` clause is used. This means any filtering will have to be carried out by SSRS.

#### Workaround options

1. We take the query above and wrap a CTE around it. This will allow us to filter based on the aggregate results.
2. Put the aggregate in a derived table.

#### CTE Example

```sql
--Filter variable
DECLARE @Filter AS int = 2
;

WITH    DataSet_CTE AS
        (
            -- Build the data set with transaction information and the aggregate column
            SELECT
                CustomerId
                ,TransactionId
                ,TransactionAttribute_1
                ,TransactionAttribute_2
                ,TransactionAttribute_3
                .
                .
                .
                ,TransactionAttribute_n
                ,COUNT(TransactionId) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId) AS CustomerTransationCount

            FROM
                Transactions
        )

-- Filter and return data       
SELECT  *
FROM    DataSet_CTE
WHERE   CustomerTransationCount > @Filter
```

#### Derived Table Example

```sql
--Filter variable
DECLARE @Filter AS int = 2
;

SELECT
    *

FROM
    (
        -- Build the data set with transaction information and the aggregate column
        SELECT
            CustomerId
            ,TransactionId
            ,TransactionAttribute_1
            ,TransactionAttribute_2
            ,TransactionAttribute_3
            .
            .
            .
            ,TransactionAttribute_n
            ,COUNT(TransactionId) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId) AS CustomerTransationCount

        FROM
            Transactions
    ) AS DataSet

WHERE
    DataSet.CustomerTransationCount > @Filter
```